# How to avoid nested working copies in Subversion?

Tags: svn

How to avoid nested working copies in Subversion?

`svn checkout` allows to checkout one working copy to subpath of another existing working copy.

For example:

```
svn checkout http://example.svn d:\wc1

svn checkout http://example.svn d:\wc1\somepath\wc1
```

I want to prevent this situation.

Is there any good approach for this?